# APIGEE on premise windows installation

Tags: apigee

I want to install APIGEE in my machine in windows, so that I can use localhost url in APIGEE proxy. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

While Apigee is more of an enterprise-scale API-Management platform, if you really want to experiment with a localhost Apigee-based API proxy on your workstation, you can. Consider using Apigee Microgateway (https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/microgateway/edge-microgateway-home), which is Node-based and can be run in Windows, or running the Apigee adapter for Envoy (https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/envoy-adapter/v2.0.x/concepts), which can run natively, or in a local Docker image, like via Windows Subsystem for Linux.